# ideas for optimizing class in Java

Tags: java, oop, optimization, constructor

This is a class I've written and it feels 'clunky', like there should be a better way to set this up without needing the extra method `setList()` to instantiate the array.  I'm trying to only leave in the parts relevant to my question, as well as an example of what I did the first time that threw a runtime (not compiletime) error.  I'm still mostly used to interpreted languages, so the stricter rules of Java are taking some getting used to.

```
public class Numbersplode
{
   // fields
   private int before;
   private int goal;
   private int[] processed;

   // constructors
   Numbersplode(int begin, int finish)
   {
      this.before = begin;
      this.goal = finish;
      this.processed = this.setList(begin);
      this.transList();
   }

   // mutators
   private int[] setList(int begin)
   {
      int[] result = new int[begin];
      return result;
   }

   public void transList()
   {
      // transforms the list
      int count;
      double temp;

      for (count = 0; count < this.before; count++)
      {
         temp = (double)count/(double)this.before * (double)this.goal;
         this.processed[count] = (int)temp;
      }
   }
}
```

It seems like I should be able to avoid having the `setList()` method, but when I tried this (everything else the same):

```
public class Numbersplode
{
   // fields
   private int before;
   private int goal;
   private int[] processed = new int[before];

   // constructors
   Numbersplode(int begin, int finish)
   {
      this.before = begin;
      this.goal = finish;
      this.transList();
   }
[..............]
```

I receive `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` since `processed[]` apparently can't be defined that way.

That extra class seems to solve the problem, but it seems to me that the Constructor should define those variables all at the same time of object creation, thus allowing for the array `processed` to be defined at the same time in that way.

So is there a more **elegant** solution I'm missing?  If I find one before this is solved I'll post it up here.

**EDIT**

Just to be clear, if I compile the class (or even a program that creates an object from that class) I don't have any problems until I actually run the program (thus the runtime problem vs compiletime, but wanted to be clear)

Comment: The reason you get the out of bounds exception is that you are instantiating the array before `before` is set in the constructor. In Java the order of operations is that the initialization section happens before the constructor body. Just instantiate the array after setting `before` like @HovercraftFullOfEels suggests.

Comment: Code edited so that I now can read the part that I missed!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Indeed, it was hiding. Hence out of bounds 0 instead of null pointer. Doesn't really change your answer though.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - I see what you mean (I think) but that's not what I'm doing with this later on in the accessors/purpose for writing this class.  I may be missing something though.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch nope, for the purpose that I'm using this for I need the resulting array to be the same as the initial array (which is what `begin` captures when the class is instantiated).  It might seem strange, but it's for the reason I need :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And why even have a `setList()` method -- a **private**(?) mutator. Why not simply set `processed = new int[before]` in your constructor?

```
Numbersplode(int before, int goal) {
  this.before = before;
  this.goal = goal;
  processed = new int[before];
  transList();
}
```